# list environment lines being truncated

Tags: listings

I am using the itemize environment to generate a list of web applications and thheir URLs as follows:

```
\documentclass{11pt,letter]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[site name:]{\url{https://this-is-a-very-long-url.example.com}}
\item[site2 name]{\url{https://this-is-an-even-longer-url-so-that-hopefully-it-will-go-beyond-the-line.example.com}}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

When I generate the pdf document, the site urls get truncated because they are too long to fit next to the site name on the same line.

Is there a way to have the text display like this?

```
site name:
  site url
site2 name:
  site2 url
```

Obviously I could use a verbatim or fancyvbr environment to accomplish this, but I would like the bullets from the list environment as well.

any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a description environment and the package `enumitem`. But what exactly do you mean with the "bullets" (you override them, don't you)?

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable!

Comment: @texnician, sorry, I am blind and sometimes the way things are printed doesn't translate into what I can tell.  So the things in the square brackets override the bullets I guess :)

Comment: @texnician,  can you provide an example of your solution?

Comment: Try something like `\usepackage{enumitem}` in the preamble and replacing the itemize environment with  `\begin{description}[style=nextline]` (and the proper ending).

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}`:

[image]

### Notes:

- The optional paramater to `\item` overrides the bullet.
- There is no mandator paramater to `\item`. Thusn, no need to have an additional `{}` around the `\url`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letter]{article}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[site name:] \url{https://this-is-a-very-long-url.example.com}
\item[site2 name] \url{https://this-is-an-even-longer-url-so-that-hopefully-it-will-go-beyond-the-line.example.com}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the description style `nextline` from `enumitem` and load `url` with the  `[hyphens]` option:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letter]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[style=nextline, font=\normalfont]
\item[Site name:] \url{https://this-is-a-very-long-url.example.com}
\item[Site2 name]\url{https://this-is-an-even-longer-url-so-that-hopefully-it-will-go-beyond-the-line.example.com}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]